# How I can correctly use command "if" in Message Dialog?

Tags: java, string, swing, conditional-statements

I`m new in Java. I would like to ask how I can use **if** in **Message Dialog?**

```
If "age" under 15, add message to new line of Message Dialog-
```

**"You`re so baby"**

I wrote this codes but it was error.Please help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Isim {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name, age, baby;
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Your name");
    age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Your Age");

    int i = new Integer(age).intValue();
    baby = "You`re so baby";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name is: "+name+"\n"+"Your Age is: "+age+"\n"+if (i < 15){baby});
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name is: "+name+"\n"+"Your Age is: "+age+"\n" + 
                                    (i < 15 ? baby : ""));
```

You can also use `String.format` method to avoid those concatenation:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your Name is: %s\n. Your Age is: %d\n. %s", name, age, (i < 15? baby: ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

For yours and other edification this is the way the problem should be solved:

```
public static final String babyMessage = " You`re so baby";
public static final int notABabyAge = 15;

public static String generateMessage(String name, int age) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Your name is: ");
  sb.append(name);
  sb.append(".  Your age is: ");
  sb.append(age);
  sb.append(".");
  if(age < notABabyAge) sb.append(babyMessage);
  return sb.toString();
}



public static void main(String args[]) {
    String name, age, message;
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Your name");
    age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Your Age");

    //Possible NumberFormatException here, enter aaa in the dialog, and boom.
    int i = new Integer(age).intValue();  
    message = generateMessage(name,age);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(message);
}
```

This kind of problems crops its head often.  Typically when interacting with a database in an application.  Often times we end up constructing an SQL statement using a combination of variables and hard coded strings.

For the hard coded strings, they are typically best to be static and final.  For variables such as notABabyAge, those kinds are thing should be coded so they can change with a configuration that occurs outside of the application.

Catching the NumberFormatException is important as people will always try to break your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this, for more readable code:

```
String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your age");
int ageInt = new Integer(age).getValue();

String babe = "";
if(ageInt < 14){
    babe = "You're so baby";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Name is: "+name+"\n"+"Your Age is: "+age+"\n"+baby);
```

Comment: Almost the best answer.  Build your string first, then pass it as a parameter.  Trouble is, poster has no interest in good coding practice.

Comment: @PeteBelford Yeah man, I just try to spread the Word ;) thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"Your Name is: "+ name + "\n" + "Your Age is: " + age + "\n" + (i < 15 ? "baby" : "")`

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) link for details.

Comment: if indicate "baby" without "" it working. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name is: "+name+"\n"+"Your Age is: "+age+"\n"+ (i < 15) ? baby : String.Empty);
```

It evaluates the condition, in this case `i < 15`, if it evaluates to true then it returns what comes after the ?, in this case `baby`, otherwise what comes after the :, an empty string (`String.Empty`).